# When I click on a link new window is opened and the session is lost completely

Tags: selenium, session, cookies, webdriver

I have opened a `html` file in browser and clicked on a particular link manually. It opens a new tab and it works fine, but if I automate it using `selenium` and click on the particular link, new blank window is opened. Where my session is lost completely.

How to retain my session?

My selenium code :

```
package projectsApi;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GetUsersPortal {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // opening my html file
        driver.get("file:///Users/lokesh-3827/Desktop/Project.html");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Get User Portals")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Get Portals')]")).click();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include here your selenium test.

Comment: try by using wait commands

Comment: @PotnuruRavi ya, I have tried using Thread.sleep . The same problem occurs.

Comment: The one i am trying to automate is not an web application, It's an Html file. Which is used for Api testing. If we click on the link it will open in new tab and give a 'Xml' response.

Comment: Are you opening an address with "file" protocol in your browser and expecting a session? Is this session the one that must be retained or the one from the new tab? Can you check that, because a session itself is to be managed by a http server or container.

Comment: @Tom 1. Yes, I am trying to open an address with 'file' protocol in my browser. 2. I can open the file properly, But when i click one of the link in the home page it open a new tab. That newly opened tab is empty. (But when i do manually, the new tab is opened with data and it's not empty).

Comment: @lokesh Can you upload your file to some place and share it? It would be easier to check. If the content is small, you can paste in your question.

Comment: @Tom Can u plz share me ur mail id, so that i can share you the file. Thank for your help.

Comment: @lokesh, we must keep everything here in SO. Please share using Github or any other site (Dropbox, Google Drive or any listed here: https://www.sitepoint.com/top-5-places-to-share-code-quickly/). Let me know when you do that.

Comment: @Tom https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7jNvTe6leYUdmNOMVU2dS1fVGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tom The problem is, In the file the method is set as 'POST' but if i call using automation the method is passed as 'GET' so am getting status '400' error in console. Where as it's working fine if i call manually (with status as 200).

Comment: @lokesh, can you include in the question your selenium script as well? For your description, I have to assume that you are not clicking the submit button using Selenium, but accessing the page redirected in each panel with driver.get("preprojects.zoho.com/portal/...").